# Assigning value to tooltip of an ASP.net Custom Validator using javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to provide a message as tooltip of a custom Validator  based on some condition in Javascript.

Can any one please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validator will no doubt spit out some HTML markup, so you could use some jQuery like this:

```
if(yourCondition) {
  $('#id-of-validator-span').attr('title', 'Your tooltip value');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Sam for the response.